# reading file as input using function in python3

Tags: python

I'm newbie I want the same output as getting the file path as input from the user using function in python 3. Please help

```
mylist=[]
f = open("C:\\Users\\dev\\Desktop\\fileparsing.txt","r")
for line in f:
    mylist.append(line)
print(mylist)
```

Output

```
['NAME: karhik\n', 'Designation: student\n', 'age: 27\n', 'sex: male\n', 'year:2017']
```

Comment: How do you want see it? As one string?

Comment: this a basic - and unclear - question. Please [edit] to add expected output

Comment: I wants same output as user has to provide the file path as input by using python function

Comment: use `f = open(input("enter filename"))` then.

Comment: Thats cool. How can I use the same as using function . like def functionname?